# Вывод имени пользователя, задавшего вопрос

Tags: предложение

В основной версии сайта в списке вопросов под заголовком и началом тела вопроса выводится имя пользователя, задавшего вопрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В мобильной версии выводится имя пользователя, который внёс последние изменения (изменил вопрос, добавил комментарий, добавил ответ, изменил ответ).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Считаю, что лучше будет везде выводить имя пользователя, задавшего вопрос.

---

Уточнение: скриншот в обеих версиях сайта был сделан при поиске по метке. На главной странице выводится последний редактор.

Comment: Ну ж спасибо - я теперь знаменитость =)

Comment: вопрос действительно заслуживает рассмотрения - в мобильной версии на моем вопросе отображается *Harry*. Думаю, действительно стоит исправить этот косячок.

Comment: @alexolut, зачем? Проблема не относится к конкретному вопросу. К тому же, если вы откроете сам вопрос, вы её не увидите. Но на всякий случай - вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/769018/3380

Comment: На основном сайте тоже последний редактор отображается.

Comment: Автор вопроса выводится на любой вкладке, кроме «текущие». В текущих — последний изменивший. Но некоторая нестыковка с мобильным сайтов всё же имеется.